# What does this expression $C^2$ mean?

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

I saw this expression on my numerical analysis class. What does $C^2[a,b]$ mean?

Comment: It means $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: a function with 2 continuous derivatives

Comment: It is worth highlighting the fact that $f$ has two _continuous_ derivatives. Surprising as it may seem, there exists differentiable functions whose derivatives are discontinuous.